# How do I fetch files with HTTP using Progress ABL?

Tags: http, progress-4gl

Is there an easy way to fetch a file using an HTTP URL with Progress ABL 10.1B without external dependencies? If so, what is the most elegant way of doing so?

I tried the documentation, but didn't seem to contain anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't link through, but you can use sockets for this. Take a look at the doc [here](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-19748).